# custom module not working after installation of new extension

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, email, smtp

i have created a custom module form and then for email functionality i installed Mageplaza extension but then my form module stopped working and when i disable Mageplaza extension module then only custom module is working. I don't understand why this happening to me. i am new to magento and want to create a form that sends email notification to admin and customer that is why i installed smtp extension but due to this my module is not working. any help will be appreciated

Comment: please specify error and proper issue. what error throwing after install SMTP?

Comment: Show your code or error what you are facing. or you can use this custom form module which working fine with email functionality.
https://github.com/mitaldeveloper/magento2-email-attachments